# Finding a function $u$

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $u$ satisfies $u_{xx}+u_{yy}=0$ in the region $x^2+y^2<9$ and the boundary condition $u=\cos^2\theta$ at $r=3$. Find $u$.

Can someone show me how to proceed with this?

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Real parts of polynomials in $z = x + i y$ are a good source of harmonic functions.

Comment: I don't understand how to apply this in my question

Comment: @user43418 Further hint: relate $\cos^2(\theta)$ with $\cos(2\theta)$, and notice that $\cos(2\theta)$ is the real part of [blank] when $r=3$.

Answer (score 0):

write $\cos^2 \theta = \frac12 + \frac12\cos 2 \theta = \text{ real part of }\frac1{18}z^2 + \frac12 \text{ on $|z| = 3$}$  and the real part of $\frac1{18}z^2 + \frac12$ is $$u = \frac1{18}(x^2 - y^2) + \frac12$$ which satisfies the laplacian and the boundary condition. i hope i didn't make any errors.